# Solr org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema in 5.2.1 customupdateprocessor

Tags: solr, processor

I was trying to develop custom update handler for **Solr 5.2.1** Version. I am facing this issue:

```
 The type org.apache.lucene.uninverting.UninvertingReader$Type
  cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
```

when I import `org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema.`

> Java version - java 1.8 
>    JRE Lib -java 1.8 
> Eclipse - Luna Release
>   (4.4.0)

**Code snippet -**

```
    import org.apache.solr.common.SolrDocument;
    import org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore;
    import org.apache.solr.request.SolrQueryRequest;
    import org.apache.solr.response.SolrQueryResponse;
    import org.apache.solr.schema.DateValueFieldType;
    import org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema;
    import org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor;
    import org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessorFactory;
    import org.apache.solr.util.plugin.SolrCoreAware;
    import org.slf4j.Logger; 
    import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
    import org.apache.solr.update.AddUpdateCommand;

     public class DocumentsFilterProcessorFactory extends   UpdateRequestProcessorFactory          
implements SolrCoreAware, DateValueFieldType {
    public final static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DocumentsFilterProcessorFactory.class);

    @Override
    public UpdateRequestProcessor getInstance(SolrQueryRequest request,
            SolrQueryResponse response, UpdateRequestProcessor nextProcessor) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return new DocumentsFilterProcessor(request, response, this,    nextProcessor);
        return null;
    }
     @Override
     public void inform(SolrCore core) {

     }
}

class DocumentsFilterProcessor extends UpdateRequestProcessor {
    IndexSchema schema=null;
    public DocumentsFilterProcessor(SolrQueryRequest req, SolrQueryResponse rsp,
    DocumentsFilterProcessorFactory factory, UpdateRequestProcessor next) {
    super(next);                                      

}    

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is something related to Eclipse. I had the same issue using 'Eclipse mars 1' and after changing to 'Eclipse mars 2' the issue is resolved.